# Improve tesseract quality with dictionary words and/or hyphenated words?

Tags: tesseract

I'm OCRing old newspapers with tesseract and am generally pleased with the results. I notice, though, that tesseract often guesses non-words that seem like they should be easily caught and corrected either with a dictionary check or some sort of probabilistic guess (e.g., like autocorrect on a phone). For example, in the passage below tesseract guesses `ar-resis` for the hyphenated word `ar-rests` and `bricf` for `brief`.

**Image input**
[image: excerpt from newspaper article]

**OCR output**

```
into the air, and making ar-
resis, The bricf battle followed
-bombarding of at least three po-
```

If you look at the attached image, both are reasonably good guesses based solely on the pixels (that is, in `brief` the second-to-last character is plausibly more like a `c` than an `e`). `bricf` is not a word that would appear in an English dictionary, though, and it is awfully close to a word that is.

This raises two related questions. First, is there a configuration option that would increase the likelihood of tesseract converting `bricf` to `brief`? I've tried increasing the penalty for non-dictionary words (`language_model_penalty_non_dict_word`) with no apparent effect.

Second, is there an option that might induce tesseract to try and re-combine hyphenated words like `ar-resis` to `arresis` (and, ideally, then compare to a dictionary to guess `arrests`)?

Comment: While tesseract is using DAWG for improving output results - its main purpose is OCR and it is not as robust for your use-cases. While using penalties, enhanced DAWG using user-defined work|pattern list may increase the confidence of extracted characters - you should still add some postprocessing to your code. For example Brief-bricf problem can easily be solved using dictionary + going through all alternatives at RIL_SYMBOL level.